# How to initialize Koin viewmodel with parameters inside a composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, koin

My viewmodel module looks like this:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { (id: Int, user: String, email: String) ->
        MyViewModel(get(), get(), id = id, user = user, email = email)
    }
}
```

so the viewmodel accepts a total of five parameters, the first two being repositories, here are modules for both of them:

```
val firstRepositoryModule = module {
    single {
        FirstRepository()
    }
}
```

```
val secondRepositoryModule = module {
    single {
       SecondRepository()
    }
}
```

i'm aware of [this sample code](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose/#viewmodel-for-composable), but here the viewmodel doesn't accept any parameters, so it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [Koin's docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel#viewmodel-and-injection-parameters) we can pass parameters to ViewModel via parametersOf() function and we can get ViewModel in composable with getViewModel(parametersOf(...)).

Example of a ViewModel with two params, string with ID of object and repository. In init{} we can use both of them:

```
class MeaningViewModel(private val meaningID: String, private val dictRepository: DictRepository) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val reply = dictRepository.getMeaningDetails(meaningID)
 ...
}
```

Koin module with repository as a singleton and ViewModel with two parameters:

```
val appModule = module {
    single<DictRepository> { DictRepositoryImpl() }
    
    viewModel { MeaningViewModel(get(), get()) }
    ...
}
```

In NavHost's composable:

```
composable(
    route = "meaning/{meaningID}",
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("meaningID") { type = NavType.StringType })
) { entry ->
    val meaningID = entry.arguments?.getString("meaningID") ?: ""
    val viewModel = getViewModel<MeaningViewModel>(
                        parameters = { parametersOf(meaningID) }
                    )
```